# How to find out whether a codec supports hardware-acceleration on Android?

Tags: android

Using Android's [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API, I can get a list of codecs registered in the system.

All the things I can get from this API are the name, supported media types and whether it is an encoder or decoder.

But how can I figure out whether a codec supports hardware-acceleration?

Comment: I guess that all provided codecs by the API are hardware ones.
Why do you need this info?

Comment: @user2399321 Why do _you_ need this info

Comment: @san The knowledge if some codec "really hw" looks useless because of resolving some tasks:  
- task 1. regular developer want to decode A encoded video. What should the app do if A is not hw accelerated?  
- task 2. regular developer want to decode A and decode it to B. What should the app do if A and B are not hw accelerated? Ok, probably B is not fixed and there's will be C on the device which is "hw", for example it will be uploaded to some server which can support C, but there always will be some next device with D which is not supported by the server.

Comment: @san task 3. not android developer[?] want to collect stats about hw codecs on different devices. In this case I believe that the guy probably will get more info somewhere at grepcode or elsewhere like this.
Best Regards.

Comment: @user2399321  Bottomline is, if you know the answer you can just answer and move on, without questioning user2885276's motives and being presumptuous. Unless what you are asking for helps compose a better answer, which I doubt.

Comment: Its also useful to know if the used codec is secondary and you have time and/or resource constrains.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Android 10 the MediaCodecAPI provides a method [isHardwareAccelerated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html#isHardwareAccelerated()) through the `MediaCodecInfo` object for each Codec.

Answer (score 1):

My smartphone has the Qualcomm Snapdragon 425 (MSM8917) SoC, and using the MediaCodecInfo app I see two encoding alternatives for the AVC(H264) codec:

- OMX.**qcom**.video.encoder.avc
- OMX.**google**.h264.encoder

As far as I know, you get access to the hardware encoding/decoding through the "qcom" package (Qualcomm), in my case, and the google one is just a software based alternative that comes with Android in case no hardware acceleration is available.

A more experienced person could confirm this.